# use populate data to filter in search mongoose

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

Hello good evening can someone help me with this question please.
I want to bring all the users by the name of the area when it exists. But the name of the area is in a populate.

I have the image but it doesn't work for me

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You [can't query by populate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#query-conditions).

But you can implement that instead:

1. First find `Area` by `nombre_area`
2. And then find `User`s with `areaI` equal to that area id

It's simple and should be performant, as I believe you don't have thousands of areas.

Comment: You are right, it is a good solution. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

you have two solutions

1- separate the query and write a method & named it aeraExist(name) and filter it by name

2- in the populate add match & if that filter doesn't match it will return null

```
    .populate({
      path: "areaI",
      match: {name: "Us"},
    })
```